# Is there a way by which I can pass a variable list to a #define directive and cause it to replace the string value by the literal value?

Tags: c++

Edit : I understand that this cannot be done using Macros, What I need is an implementation of a variable param-list template function for C98. Or a better way to approach this problem.Please suggest..

**e.g.**:

```
#define TEST_RUN(_retType, _funcName,_paramList)
({
    _retType (*funcPtr)(_paramList) = _funcName;
    _retType a = funcPtr;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
})
```

and I pass to this :

```
void someFunc(){
    std::string retType = "int";
    std::string paramList = "int, int";
    std::string funcName = foo;
    TEST_RUN(retType, funcName, paramList);
}
```

Function foo :

```
int foo( int a, int b){
    return a>b?a:b;
}
```

The basic idea is to *reate a variable param list* and *return type for a function pointer* for a **c98 compiler**

Comment: You can't do that. The variables `retType`, `paramList` and `funcName` are not defined until compilation, which is after the preprocessor runs.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I understand why we cannot use #define. As we dont have Variadic templates until C11, is there a way by which I can achieve similar functionality in C98? Say using some boost functionality?

Comment: @user1928281: See my answer, C++ has a strict separation beween compile-time (before a single line of code has run) and run-time (after the whole code has been compiled). Variadic templates won't solve that either.

Comment: I understand that MSalters :) I am trying to perform this task post compilation, without using #define. What I need is an implementation of a variable param-list template function for C98.
Or a better way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2):

"variables" and "strings" exist in a later phase of compilation; the preprocessor runs at the stage where you have mere tokens. Your idea cannot be made to work in C++.

Not a C++98 problem, either: the same phases of compilation still apply to C++17, and I would be highly surprised if they ever change. More fundamentally, you assume an interpreted language when you write `std::string paramList = "int, int"`. At the time where you have an actual `std::string variable`, the compiler must have run in the past, but that `int,int` is *input* to the compiler. An interpreter can interpret new code while existing code is running, but a compiler does not.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Macros are no more than text substation, with limited capabilities. They do not see values in objects (like `std::string`) or even the type system.

A macro does nothing more than tell the preprocessor to transform a sequence of characters in the **source code** to another sequence of characters in the source code, before the compiler even starts parsing it.

Comment: _"Macros are no more than text substation"_ substitution* _"A macro does nothing more than tell the preprocessor to transform a sequence of characters in the source code to another sequence of characters in the source code"_ That's not true. Macros perform _token_ substitution, which is quite different! -1

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, to quote one of my favorite mathematicians *"There's no sense in being precise when you don't even know what you're talking about."* I really have nothing more to add when faced with your style of uncommunicative comments.

Comment: I'm sorry you did not like my comment and the factual statement it provided to correct your inaccurate answer! I can assure you, though, that I _do_ "know what I'm talking about" in this particular case. Have a lovely evening :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, heaven forbid if I or anyone ever doubt your impeccable knowledge. The OP however, does not seem to be as well versed in the intricate nature of the language. I'd lay down another quote about explaining things simply (albeit inaccurately), but I'd hate for that to be understood as an insult as well. Oh, and have a fantastic evening yourself :)

Comment: I don't think it's particularly responsible to provide false information to someone who doesn't know any better than to believe it, no!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Yes your outrage was quite clear in your previous comment(s). However, a discussion about the value of various levels of accuracy to one's learning curve seems to be out of scope here, and possibly even on meta.

Comment: I guess this is why we're discouraged from explaining our downvotes. Sigh.